# searching for words in a text file in java

Tags: java

I am trying to search for words within a text file and replace all upper-cased with lower-cased characters. The problem is that when I use the replace All function using a regular expression I get a syntax error. I have tried different tactics, but it doesn't work. Any tips? I think that maybe I should create a replace All method that I would have to invoke, but I don't really see its use.

```
public static void main()  throws FileNotFoundException {

    ArrayList<String> inputContents = new ArrayList<>();

    Scanner inFile =
     new Scanner(new FileReader("H:\\csc8001\\data.txt"));

     while(inFile.hasNextLine())
     {
      String line = inFile.nextLine();
       inputContents.add(inFile.nextLine());

     }
     inFile.close();

     ArrayList<String> dictionary = new ArrayList<>();


     for(int i= 0; i <inputContents.size(); i++)
     {
      String newLine = inFile.nextLine();
      newLine = newLine(i).replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]");
      dictionary.add(inFile.nextLine());

     }


    // PrintWriter outFile =
    // new PrintWriter("H:\\csc8001\\results.txt");

}
```

Comment: Please, format your code properly.

Comment: Please look at the String's replaceAll method: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_replaceall.htm

Answer (score 3):

There is a compilation error on this line:

```
newLine = newLine(i).replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]");
```

Because [`replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) takes 2 parameters: a regex and a replacement.
(And because `newLine(i)` is non-sense.)
This should be closer to what you need:

```
newLine = newLine.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]+", " ");
```

That is, replace non-empty sequences of non-`[A-Za-z0-9]` characters with a space.

To convert all uppercase letters to lowercase, it's simpler and better to use [`toLowerCase`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toLowerCase(java.util.Locale)).

There are many other issues in your code too. For example, some lines in the input will be skipped, due to some inappropriate `inFile.nextLine` calls. Also, the input file is closed after the first loop, but the second tries to use it, which makes no sense.

With these and a few other issues cleaned up, this should be closer to what you want:

```
Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new FileReader("H:\\csc8001\\data.txt"));

List<String> inputContents = new ArrayList<>();
while (inFile.hasNextLine()) {
    inputContents.add(inFile.nextLine());
}
inFile.close();

List<String> dictionary = new ArrayList<>();
for (String line : inputContents) {
     dictionary.add(line.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]+", " ").toLowerCase());
}
```

If you want to add words to the dictionary instead of lines, you also need to split the lines on spaces. One simple way to achieve that:

```
    dictionary.addAll(Arrays.asList(line.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]+", " ").toLowerCase().split(" ")));
```

Comment: so in your opinion, it's  better to create another method whose functionnality woud be use used in the main method in order to perform the requested task whether it be to replaceAll or toLowerCase?

Comment: I was sightseeing to simply replace `replaceAll` with `toLowerCase`. I added more explanation in case it helps, see my update

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I just have one last question, how did you manage to remove all non words from the inputContents list? how to make sure that there are no exclamations marks and other caracters involved?

Comment: @Jazztheman ok I actually missed something in your question. I updated my answer, I hope it answers your follow-up question in the comment too.

Comment: Hey man, yes, I think you can help me further as my regular expression isn't working and my output is empty. basically the target is to get all words, convert them to lower case, put them in a dictionary on an alphabetical order, one word per line without duplication then output the dictionary in another file. the problem is that the end prdduct is empty. and I don't know why. using your logic, I ended up with the code below

Comment: @Jazztheman it sounds like you have some new problems, which should be in a new question (and perhaps you can accept this one)

Comment: you are right, sorry i didn't clarify correctly. your logic was correct. the problem is that on the final stage, I was getting an empty result instead of outputing words in a lower case format. i reckoned, the issue might either be from regex I had used or the arrangement of my codes within loops or the dictionary. addAll function you had used. I just wanted to give you as much details of what was required and show you my code so that you can help determine where I got it wrong

Comment: @Jazztheman there are many things going wrong in your new code, and that's another reason why it belongs in a new question. Anyway, use my last suggestion in the answer to put all the words in the dictionary list. It works. Then, to make the words unique and sorted, do this: `Set<String> sorted = new TreeSet<>(dictionary);`. That should be about it.